# Uneven spacing in IEEE bibliography entries!

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, ieeetran

I am writing a IEEE journal article, the entire reference file is done in JabTex and all the entries seem pretty alright. I am referring to around 200+ papers. However when I build the file the first two pages of my bibliography are alright, then all of a sudden the spacing between the paragraphs changes. Here is my code. Just the initial and ending parts.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\listfiles
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
```

Followed by....

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ppy}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliographyproblem]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be really helpful here.

Comment: If you can only find what part is causing the change, it will probably be obvious in hindsight. One may suspect be the last entry that looks OK, or the first one that doesn't look OK. Take away all your text except for `\cite` for those two, and regenerate. Still a problem? In that case maybe you can isolate which one of those two entries it is.

Comment: Entry 173 looks suspect to me: not only is it the last apparently OK entry, but it has some odd formatting. Try what pst suggests: or try *removing* citation to 173 then 174 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Yeah, or just inspect that bib entry to see if there is anything strange in it. The reason I said to keep the strange part was that if the problem can't be determined then by user49012 that's the way to a minimal problem showing the problem to us.

Comment: I think it's math in entry 173 that isn't ended.

Comment: I remember this happening to me too but I don't remember the exact cause. Remove all those bibliography balancing commands and IEEE custom directives first and try again.

Comment: I guess the problem was with bibliography entry no. 173. The math operator was not stopped. Thank you all for your suggestions. I am quite new at this Latex and all of you had been really helpful. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

with current TeXLive (the bib is part of TeXLive):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\def\BibTeX{Bib\TeX}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you get the same output then there is a problem with your bib data. Provide the `*.bib` file for testing.